# Rails delete function, link and route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, haml

I'm trying to add a delete function to my custom built cms, I have the following table in my view:

```
%table.table.table-hover{ :cellspacing => "0", :cellpadding => "0" }
  %thead
    %th Title
    %th

  - Glossary.find(:all, :order => "title ASC").each do |c|
    %tr{ :onclick => "window.location='/cms/other/glossary/#{ c.id }'" }
      %td= c.title
      %td
```

with this in my controller:

```
def glossary_destroy
  @del = Glossary.find(params[:id])
  @del.destroy

  redirect_to "/cms/other/glossary"
end
```

However I don't know what to put in my routes, or how to put a link into my view to make this work?

This is the rest of my routes:

```
['glossary', 'gallery'].each do |p|

  match "/cms/other/#{p}" => "cms##{p}"
  match "/cms/other/#{p}/:id" => "cms##{p}_edit"
  match "/cms/other/#{p}-add" => "cms##{p}_add"
  match "/cms/other/#{p}-edit-process" => "cms##{p}_editprocess"
  match "/cms/other/#{p}-add-process" => "cms##{p}_addprocess"

end
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using a destroy method with `resources :glossaries` in routes?

Answer (score 0):

destroy is REST function, so you don't need to explicitly add anything in your routes.rb if you have already added

```
resources :glossaries
```

in your routes.

in your view (inside .each) you can call this using link_to

```
link_to "destroy", c, method: :delete
```

add this in your routes file with other routes you have added

```
match "/cms/other/#{p}/:id" => "cms##{p}_destroy", :via => :delete
```

Comment: I've added my current routes to the question

Comment: I've tried that and I get `undefined method 'glossary_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000003510088>:0x00000003136188>`

Comment: how about adding `resources :glossaries` in your routes.rb

Comment: I'm not sure that would help me as i'd have to move files around or rename them?